# Calling a parameterized javascript function from php

Tags: php, javascript

I need to call a javascript function from php, by passing a value in php variable. My code goes like this:

```
echo '<tr class="trlight"><td onclick="callVehicle('.$qry_vehicleid.');"><label>Call Vehicle</label>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
```

And in javascript file I try to execute the following code:

```
function callVehicle(vid)
{
alert('Call '+vid);
document.getElementById("SearchResult").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

and an error `test is not defined` occurs. `test` is the value that I assigned to variable `$qry_vehicleid`. Can someone please point out what the mistake is?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding quotes around your inserted PHP variable.

```
echo '<tr class="trlight"><td onclick="callVehicle(\''.$qry_vehicleid.\'');"><label>Call Vehicle</label>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple of quotes, what you are echoing is:

```
<td onclick="callVehicle(test);">
```

and what you want is:

```
<td onclick="callVehicle('test');">
```

since `test` is a string parameter. Your code should be:

```
echo '<tr class="trlight"><td onclick="callVehicle(\''.$qry_vehicleid.'\');"><label>Call Vehicle</label>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you PHP code to

```
echo '<tr class="trlight"><td onclick="callVehicle('.json_encode($qry_vehicleid).');"><label>Call Vehicle</label>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
```

Naively adding quotes around your value is going to bite you at some point if you try to use a value that already has quotes in it.